# How to convert returned value of List.Take(1);

Tags: c#, ienumerable

i have a code like this:

```
List<double[]>t;
for(...){ t.Add(elem)};
```

where 'elem' is a 'double[]', of course;

next, i want to take all elements of list:

```
double [] d;
for(int i = 0; i<t.Length; ++i){
 d = t.Take(1); // take first element
 t.RemoveAt(0); // deleting first element, yes?
}
```

but Take() method return 'Ienumerable'; 
how to convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Take` returns an `IEnumerable` of `double[]`, which, when you call `ToArray()`, returns the `double[][]` type, which is probably not what you're looking for.

Aren't you simply looking for a simple `t[0]` to get the first element (or even better, `t.First()`)?

Answer (score 4):

You should use First instead of Take(1)

```
t.First()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
 t.First();
```

which returns the 1st element of the collection, while `.Take(n)` returns the first n elements as a collection.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need LINQ if you simply want to take the first element of the list and remove it afterwards.

```
for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; ++i) {
    double[] d = t[0];
    t.RemoveAt(0);

    // ...
}
```

Depending on what you are doing, you could also process the whole list before emptying it.

```
foreach (double[] d in t) {
    // ...
}

t.Clear();
```